# Where to download pdflatex.exe?

Tags: pdftex, installing

I ran a Google search but nothing too clear showed up. I'm looking for a Windows 7 compatible version of pdflatex.exe to help me in typesetting some math I have in an Illustrator project.

Comment: Are you sure they are talking about `pdflatex.exe` and not about [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/)?

Answer (score 59):

`pdflatex.exe` is part of a whole suite of software called a TeX Distribution. You can't just download the executable.  There are two main distributions available for Windows: TeX Live and MikTeX.  Both are very good.  Whether or not installing them and learning  enough LaTeX to solve your problem is a worthwhile effort may well depend on how often you are likely to do what you're doing.

Here are links to the distribution download pages:

- [MiKTeX Project Page](http://miktex.org)
- [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/)

See the following question on the differences between the two distributions.

[What are the advantages of TeX Live over MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20036/2693)

If this is a one off type situation, you may also want to take a look at some of the online LaTeX compilers:

[Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/2693)

Comment: If you're a beginner, proTeXt, which includes MiKTeX, might also be a good idea; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26021/4012.

Comment: Well, you *can* download it. Whether there is any *point* doing so is, of course, a different matter.

Answer (score 9):

I can not get the motivation behind asking only for `pdflatex`. Nevertheless, (for windows) you can download 'MiKTeX' basic installer and install. You can find `pdflatex` in the folder `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin`.

If your intention is for writing some equations, you can try [`Mathtype`](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/). It has compatibility with many applications including Adobe Illustrator and InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

[W32TeX](http://w32tex.org) offers this. It can be found at [a mirror](http://ctan.ijs.si/mirror/w32tex/current) under *pdftex-w32*.

To get it to compile TeX you will also need the *web2c-w32* and *web2c-lib*
packages. If you want to compile LaTeX, add *latex* package as well.