# Installing pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texlive

I've been working with miktex for a while, recently I installed texlive instead, and found pdflatex for each manager is different, I'd like to unninstall pdflatex from the texlive manager and install pdflatex from miktex. Where do I find the it? I need it because of the option -include-directory=DIR

[Where to download pdflatex.exe?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49569/where-to-download-pdflatex-exe)

Comment: You can't use the pdflatex from miktex in texlive. It needs an "miktex environment".

Comment: You can't (easily) use pdfLaTeX from one distro with the packages from another. However, I'm not sure what you mean about them being different: other than very minor versions they'll be the same release.

Comment: @JosephWright in miktex pdflatex has quite a number of command line options which doesn't exist in texlive - like the `include-directory` option which appends on the fly folders to the search path.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I realise that but the pdfTeX 'business end' is the same (1.40....)

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix TeX binaries of different TeX distributions. If you like to use `pdflatex` of MiKTeX, install a minimal MiKTeX. To avoid doubling of all packages you can install the TEXMF tree of TeX Live (usually `texlive/<year>/texmf-dist`) as an additional TEXMF root with MiKTeX settings.

As an alternative you could fake the `-include-directory` option using a batch, that extends TEXINPUTS variable before calling TeX Live's `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, pdflatex.exe is located here

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` assuming you install miktex into the folder I show here.

Did I correctly understand your question?