# Does Windows version of TeX contain patgen?

Tags: hyphenation, windows, distributions, patgen

I know two Windows versions of TeX -- MiKTeX and proTeXt. Do they contain patgen package? If not, what Windows version of TeX contain the package? Can MiKTeX or proTeXt import such package from TeX distribution? If yes, how to do it? If the package can be imported to Windows version, can you give a very simple example command line to show how to use it?

Comment: `MikTeX` and `proTeXt` are the same LaTeX distrubution,. `proTeXt` just adds a few extra tools in an easy manner. For windows there are two free LaTeX dists: `MikTeX` and `TeX Live`, for the later see Martins answer

Comment: For some more details about the difference between MiKTeX and proTeXt, see my answer at [What to download, proTeXt or MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26021).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MiKTeX 2.9 does not contain patgen, but the Windows version of [TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) has a `patgen.exe` for Win32.