# What Linux operating system contains patgen for hyphenation?

Tags: tex-core, texlive, hyphenation, patgen

This question follows [previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52589/how-to-use-translate-file-correctly-in-patgen-of-texlive). In TexLive, patgen command prompts error of "No such file or directory". I found at [About.com](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/patgen.htm) that Linux contains patgen. I have Linux Red Hat 9.0 in my system. Can you let me know if it has this patgen command, in what directory?

Comment: "command does not seem to work" is not an appropriate problem description, please tell what you have tried, what has happened etc. Furthermore I'm confused by "Red Hat 9.0" since the current version of RHEL is 6.2.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: He probably means [Fedora 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fedora_versions#Fedora_9) - which is from May _2008_. Or he really is using [Red Hat Linux 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux#Version_history), which is from _2003_.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I am installing Linux Red Hat 9.0, not Fedora.

Comment: Why are you using Red Hat 9? Do you have really *really* old hardware? Even in that case, there is virtually no good reason to install such an old Linux distribution, and many good reasons not to!

Comment: @Warren: That's _9_, not _9.0_. Why are you installing an OS from _2003_? Anyway: You may find a version of teTeX or TeXLive from 2003 in the net that will work on that. Good hunting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question "does Linux contain `patgen`" is meaningless. There is no *Linux*, there are many operating systems based on the Linux kernel, but which differ in many aspects from one another.

A GNU/Linux based distribution may even not have TeX, if its developing team decides not to include it.

If you have a Red Hat system, then the only way to know whether `patgen` is available is to look for it in the directories containing executable programs.

See http://www.tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html

> **TeX provided by your operating system**
>
> First, you may have gotten a TeX installation that was based on TeX Live but was packaged for your operating system. For instance, the free GNU/Linux distributions, and the distributions from Red Hat, Debian, Ubuntu, SUSE, etc., all make TeX installations derived from TeX Live available through their normal packaging system (`rpm`, `apt-get`, `yum`, etc.). If this is how you got your TeX, the timing and content of updates is entirely up to your operating system provider—contact them with any and all questions.
>
> By the way, a native TL, which is typically installed under `/usr/local`, and a TeX from your operating system can happily coexist, each with their own completely independent trees and programs. (Do not try to merge them!) So you could install a native TeX Live if your vendor is not keeping up.

Comment: i have a machine with red hat 9, here: it has patgen, in /usr/bin; i have never used it.  i wouldn't recommend even  trying patgen on such an outdated os version!

Comment: i wouldn't expect any recent tex live to work on such an ancient distro as red hat 9.  i have several tex systems on mine; the latest is tetex 2!