# Glossary of TeX and LaTeX terms

Tags: documentation

This is not about glossary package. :-)
I was wondering whether there is a list of common terms you come across as a not-so-advanced user, defined already. Currently what we have are many books containing commands. But is there any compilation of all (that may be confusing for some) terms such as macro, command, style files, class files etc. ? If there isn't already, I was thinking of creating one—an alphabetically ordered document with definitions and simple examples. This would help users understand the technically advanced answers here in tex.sx too. If you think there isn't such a source, let me know the terms you would like to see included!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by this glossary. How about [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org) or [TeXdoc](http://texdoc.net/)?

Comment: I had in mind a non-specialised document for starters, perhaps referencing to TeXdoc items for details. Yep CTAN would be defined, surely as one of the _terms_ :-)

Comment: It isn't alphabetically ordered, but my [definitions chapter](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/definitions.html) defines common terms.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The following is an attempt at creating a glossary of (La)TeX-related terms. The definitions are intentionally very short. If there are related question that ask about the term are tags corresponding to the term, links are provided.

This is a CW answer, so please add additional terms and/or definition and fix any errors you might find.

- **active character**:
- **AMS-TeX**: A *→macro* system based on *→plain TeX* designed to support the input of mathematical notation, including display material, in a manner comfortable for a user familiar with the language of mathematics.
- **AMS-LaTeX**: A "translation" of *→AMS-TeX* into *→LaTeX* syntax, with the addition of several *→document classes* and related *→packages* conforming to the style specifications of the American Mathematical Society. Cf. [amsmath](/questions/tagged/amsmath), [amsart](/questions/tagged/amsart), [amsbook](/questions/tagged/amsbook) and [amsthm](/questions/tagged/amsthm)
- **argument**: A command *acts* on a variable which is itself made of a set of characters. This variable is called the argument
- **AUCTeX**: An interface for writing and formating *→TeX*, *→LaTeX* and *→ConTeXt* documents in the GNU Emacs text editor. Cf. [auctex](/questions/tagged/auctex)
- **biber**: External program used for sorting bibliography data. Designed to be used with `biblatex`.  See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693) and [biber](/questions/tagged/biber)
- **biblatex**: LaTeX package offering advanced bibliography formatting possibilities. See  [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693) and [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex)
- **BibTeX**: External program used for sorting bibliography data and formatting it. Usually used in conjunction with a bibliographic package such as `natbib` or `biblatex`. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693) and [bibtex](/questions/tagged/bibtex)
- **big point**: A *→dimension* unit where 1 inch = 72 big points.  See also *→point*. Note that outside of the TeX world a big point is usually simply called a (PostScript) point.
- **box**:
- **catcode**: short for *→category code*.
- **category code**: Each *→character* is assigned a character code that tells TeX how to interpret it. See [What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes) and [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do/). Cf. [catcodes](/questions/tagged/catcodes).
- **character**:
- **character class**:
- **.cls**: see *→document class*.
- **class**: see *→document class*.
- **command**: Usually used synonymously with *→macro* and *→control sequence*.
- **comment**: An uncompiled string, starting with %, generally used for making notes and making code understandable to others and oneself. Blocks of sentences can be made comments by using a separate package.
- **compilation**: The process of turning (TeX) *→source code* into an *→output format*. Cf. [compiling](/questions/tagged/compiling)
- **Computer Modern**: The *→font* family created by *→Donald Knuth* for use with *→TeX*, based on Monotype 8A, the font used in the original printings of his book series *The Art of Computer Programming*.
- **ConTeXt**: A *→format* that aims to provide a modern alternative to *→LaTeX*. Cf. [context](/questions/tagged/context)
- **ConTeXt Mk II**: The previous version of *→ConTeXt*, based on *→pdfTeX*. Cf. [context-mkii](/questions/tagged/context-mkii)
- **ConTeXt Mk IV**: The current version of *→ConTeXt*, based on *→LuaTeX*. Cf. [context-mkiv](/questions/tagged/context-mkiv)
- **control sequence**: The original term given by *→Donald Knuth* to what is now more often called a *→macro*. Control sequences are of two kinds: *→control words* and *→control symbols*.
- **control symbol**: A *→control sequence* that consists of a backslash plus one non-letter, e.g. `\,`.
- **control word**: A *→control sequence* that consists of a backslash plus one or more letters, e.g. `\i` or `\input`.
- **counter**:
- **CTAN**: The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network; a network of file servers that contain most things related to *→TeX*, e.g. the *→engines*, major *→formats* and *→LaTeX*  *→packages*. Available at [www.ctan.org](http://www.ctan.org/).
- **DANTE**: The German-speaking *→TeX* User Group called "Deutschsprachige Anwendervereinigung TeX e.V.", visit [www.dante.de](http://www.dante.de).
- **definition**: The association of a meaning or *→expansion* to a *→control sequence* (= *→macro*).  In *→plain TeX* this may be accomplished by `\def` or `\let`; in *→LaTeX* the recommended mechanism is to use `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`.
- **dimension**:
- **distribution**: A complete set of TeX binaries, associated scripts and external programs and packages. There are two major distributions: *→TeX Live* (cross platform) and *→MiKTeX* (Windows). *→MacTeX* is a version of TeX Live for the Mac. Cf. [distributions](/questions/tagged/distributions)
- **document class**: Is a file containing the general layout of a *→LaTeX* document. It is loaded with `\documentclass{⟨name⟩}`, typically at the first line of the document. Examples are `letter`, `article`, `book`, `memoir` and the *→KOMA-Script* classes. Cf. [document-classes](/questions/tagged/document-classes) and [documentclass-writing](/questions/tagged/documentclass-writing)
- **Donald E. Knuth**: The author of *→TeX*.
- **.dtx**:
- **DVI**: The *device independent file format*, the original output format of *→TeX*. Can be viewed with a DVI-viewer, but is usually converted to *→PostScript* or *→PDF*. Cf. [dvi](/questions/tagged/dvi)
- **encoding**: Usually used in reference to either *→font encoding* or *→input encoding*.
- **engine**: A program that can *→compile*  *→TeX*  *→source code*. The major engines besides *→Donald Knuth*'s original TeX (now in version 3.1415926) are *→pdfTeX*, *→LuaTeX* and *→XeTeX*. See [The differences between TeX engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/2693).
- **environment**:
- **error**:
- **ε-TeX** (often written as **e-TeX**): An extension to *→TeX* that is supported by all modern *→engines* and *→distributions*. Cf. [etex](/questions/tagged/etex)
- **expansion**:
- **float**: A type of *→environment*, used to separate content such as tables, diagrams or pictures from rest of the document. Its position in the final document might not be exactly where it is placed in the *→source*, as it can “float” to a different location in the document based upon options defined in the document and where *→LaTeX* (or *→ConTeXt*) thinks it fits best. Cf. [floats](/questions/tagged/floats)
- **font**:
- **font encoding**: A mapping between source characters and glyphs in a particular font. See [fontenc vs inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44694/2693) and [font-encodings](/questions/tagged/font-encodings)
- **format**:
- **fragile**: A *→command* that will expand when used in a *→moving argument* in such a way as to cause problems or failure is said to be "fragile". See *→protect*.
- **group**:
- **input encoding**: A mapping between keystrokes and characters in a source document. See [fontenc vs inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44694/2693)
- **JabRef**: A reference manager for *→BibTeX*. Cf. [jabref](/questions/tagged/jabref)
- **Knuth**: See *→Donald E. Knuth*.
- **KOMA-Script**:
- **LaTeX**: A commonly used *→format* of *→TeX*. Cf. [latex-project](/questions/tagged/latex-project)
- **LaTeX2ε** (often written **LaTeX2e**): The current version of *→LaTeX*.
- **LaTeX 3**: The next version of *→LaTeX*. It has been in development for some time and, while significant progress has been made, the release date is yet unknown. Cf. [latex3](/questions/tagged/latex3)
- **LaTeX Project Public License**:
- **Latin Modern**:
- **Leslie Lamport**: The original author of *→LaTeX*.
- **LPPL**: The *→LaTeX Project Public License*.
- **LuaTeX**: An *→engine* that includes the Lua scripting language to make programming in *→TeX* easier. It also includes support for *→Unicode* and *→OpenType* fonts. It is based on *→pdfTeX* and is needed to use *→ConTeXt Mk IV*. Cf. [luatex](/questions/tagged/luatex)
- **LyX**: A document processing system that provides a GUI front-end to LaTeX. Cf. [lyx](/questions/tagged/lyx)
- **macro**: Basically anything in the *→TeX*  *→source code* that starts with a backslash `\`. They are processed by TeX by first *→expanding* them and then processing the remaining *→primitives*. A synonym of *→control sequence*. Cf. [macros](/questions/tagged/macros)
- **MacTeX**: A *→distribution* for Mac OS, based on *→TeX Live*. Cf. [mactex](/questions/tagged/mactex)
- **microtype**: a *→package* that allows for subtle and detailed adjustments of spacing and character positioning.
- **MiKTeX**: A *→distribution* for Windows. Cf. [miktex](/questions/tagged/miktex)
- **moving argument**: The *→argument* of a *→macro* that stores its contents in auxiliary files and re-inserts them on later *→compilation* runs.  The argument is thus expanded multiple times asynchronously.
- **OpenType font**:
- **output format**:
- **package** (LaTeX): A file (or collection of files) that extend or change the capabilities of *→LaTeX*. Packages are used in a document by adding `\usepackage{⟨package-name⟩}` in the *→preamble*. Cf. [packages](/questions/tagged/packages) and [package-writing](/questions/tagged/package-writing).
- **package** (generic): A collection of files and documentation that is present on *→CTAN* or in *→distributions*. It can be a LaTeX package, LaTeX class, collection of fonts etc.
- **parameter**:
- **PDF**: The *Portable Document Format* is a commonly used file format for electronic documents. It is usually created by *→TeX* by converting a *→DVI* file or by using *→pdfTeX*. Cf. [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf)
- **pdfTeX**: A *→TeX*  *→engine* that can produce *→PDF* output directly. It also supports the *→ε-TeX* extensions and *→microtype*. Current distributions use pdfTeX even when creating a *→DVI* file. Cf. [pdftex](/questions/tagged/pdftex)
- **pgf**: (for “portable graphics format”) is a set of macros for generating graphics. Usually it is not used directly, but rather through the nicer syntax provided by its companion *→TikZ*. In the TikZ/pgf package, pgf is referred to as the “basic layer“, while TikZ is a “frontend layer”. Cf. [pgf-core](/questions/tagged/pgf-core)
- **Plain TeX**: Is the original *→format* created by *→Donald Knuth*. It provides some additional *→commands*, but far less than *→LaTeX* or *→ConTeXt* do. Cf. [plain-tex](/questions/tagged/plain-tex)
- **point**: Also called “printer's point” or “TeX point”. The basic typographic *→dimension*  unit, where 1 inch = 72.27 points. See also *→big point*. Note that outside of the TeX world, *point* usually refers to a big point.
- **PostScript**: A programming language best known as a page description language used by laser printers. The *→PSTricks* suite of packages allow Postscript "specials" to be incorporated into TeX documents, allowing access the full power of the Postscript language. PostScript is often used as an intermediary step when creating a *→PDF* document.
- **preamble**: Is the part of a *→LaTeX* document before `\begin{document}` where the user sets the specification of the document as a whole and the *→packages* to be loaded for the *→commands* to come later in the body. Cf. [preamble](/questions/tagged/preamble)
- **primitive**: A command already defined by *→TeX* when it starts up. Ultimately all macros reduce to primitives. The majority of them  correspond to commands executed in the inner parts of *→TeX*, but some never reach that stage because they behave similarly to macros in that they're expandable (conditionals and `\expandafter` are of this type).    They are somewhat similar to the keywords in a programming language.
- **protect**: A mechanism to prevent a *→fragile →command* from being expanded when used in a *→moving argument*.  This can be applied ad hoc using the command `\protect` or when defining the command with `\DeclareRobustCommand`.
- **proTeXt**: A software bundle for Windows consisting of the *→distribution*  *→MiKTeX*, the editor TeXstudio (earlier versions had TeXnicCenter instead), Ghostscript and GSView. It aims to provide an easy way of installing a complete setup to new LaTeX users. Cf. [protext](/questions/tagged/protext) and [What to download, proTeXt or MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26018/what-to-download-protext-or-miktex).
- **PS**: see *→PostScript*.
- **PSTricks**: A set of macros that allow the inclusion of *→PostScript* drawings directly inside TeX or LaTeX code. It is originally the work of Timothy Van Zandt and in recent years it has been maintained by Denis Girou, Sebastian Rahtz and Herbert Voß. Cf. [pstricks](/questions/tagged/pstricks)
- **robust**: The technique of writing *→macros* to be safe to use in a *→moving argument*; i.e. one whose behavior does not change if it is *→expanded* multiple times.
- **semantic markup**:
- **source code**:
- **space**:
- **.sty**: see *→package*.
- **style file**: A term that is not officially used in *→LaTeX2e*. Can refer either to a *→package* or a *→document class*.
- **template**:
- **terminal**:
- **TeX**: A typesetting language and processor. Cf. [tex-general](/questions/tagged/tex-general)
- **TeX by Topic**: A book by Victor Eijkhout that describes, mainly for *→macro* writers, the structure of *→TeX* and its *→commands* in chapters “concerned with relatively small, well-delineated topics“.
- **texdoc**: A command line utility for accessing documentation. For example, `texdoc ⟨package⟩` will show the documentation for `⟨package⟩`. It is also available online at [www.texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net/). Cf. [texdoc](/questions/tagged/texdoc)
- **TeX Live**: A *→distribution* maintained by *→TUG*. Available for all major PC operating systems. Cf. [texlive](/questions/tagged/texlive)
- **The TeX Book**: The book by *→Donald Knuth* that describes how the *→TeX* typesetting system works, and how to use it.
- **TikZ**: (Coordinate-based) package that enhances graphic-building capabilities. It is a frontend to *→pgf*. Cf. [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf)
- **token**:
- **TrueType font**:
- **TUG**: The *→TeX* User Group, an organization representing the interests of TeX users worldwide. Visit [tug.org](http://tug.org).
- **TUGboat**: The journal of *→TUG*.
- **Type 1 font**:
- **Unicode**: A character set enabling the use of most of the world's writing systems in a single document. UTF-8 is a popular encoding for storing Unicode documents. The Unicode standard is maintained by the [Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/).
- **warning**:
- **XeTeX**: A modern *→engine* that supports *→Unicode* and *→OpenType* fonts. Cf. [xetex](/questions/tagged/xetex)

See also [File extensions related to LaTeX, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-of-latex-related-files)

Comment: A lot of valuable information might already be in our tag wikis, which should in some way be taken into account here.

Comment: Then maybe we should create an extended version of the tag descriptions?

Comment: @CountZero: Not every term corresponds to a tag. But improving the tag wikis is always a good idea :)

Comment: @CountZero: I'd suggest to do it just the other way round: Keep the descriptions here really short, but link to the tag wiki if there is a good one (if not, make one, maybe); all in the spirit of http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1870/4012.

Comment: @Caramdir: Thanks for being a good experienced user, correcting my entries and helping us not-so-advanced users learn. Cheers and God bless

Comment: I've also been adding links to canonical questions on the site regarding the definitions if they're available.

Comment: Once developed, this list might make a nice addition to the documentation available on CTAN?

Comment: @Ryan: Instead of "A style of →macros that is safe to use in a →moving argument", could you also say a "category" or "kind"? That'd sound clearer to me, "style" is a bit of a soft term.

Comment: @Caramdir -- not sure who wrote the entry for "float", but you're the last person who edited it.  i don't believe that a float can move to a "previous" page; yes, it can appear *before* it is located in the source, but only to the top of the same page.  if i'm wrong, please correct me; if not, please correct the entry.  thanks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It seemed strange to me too, but I'm far from an expert on floats. The original comes from jClark94, I just edited it a bit.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I shortened the entry a bit more, avoiding being too specific.

Comment: Is this list inactive/closed, or can be updated? There are many empty entries...