# Basic setup for LaTeX for Mac?

Tags: mactex, distributions

I have a professor who requires me to use Latex but he mainly speaks in terms of PC. I have a Mac so I have to find appropriate alternatives. So far I have purchased "Latexian" as an editor, and see that the MikTeX distribution is mainly for PC. It seems that the alternative for Mac is Mactex.

Am I correct?
Is there any other concern I should consider?
Out of curiosity, why wouldn't Latexian have a built in installer, since it can obviously generate live PDF views anyway?

Comment: The title of the question should be more informative.

Comment: MacTeX is indeed the main distribution for Mac. It's the Mac version of  TeX Live,, which is multi-platform.

Comment: You could take a look at [Glossary of TeX and LaTeX terms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58431) to familiarize yourself with some key concepts related to LaTeX: compilation, distribution, engine, etc.

Comment: There are lots of editors for LaTeX: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides. As you've paid for one, I guess you'll go with that, but there are lots of free alternatives (many cross-platform with Windows/Linux).

Comment: [texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) looks good.

Answer (score 2):

As others have remarked, the nearest equivalent to MikTeX on Mac OS X is [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/). Alternately, you could install [BasicTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) for a smaller and less capable download. The [Latexian FAQ](http://tacosw.com/latexian/support.php) addresses this in a minor note, which seems odd given the importance of TeX for a LaTeX IDE.

As to why Latexian doesn't include a built-in installer for TeX, I'd guess that the sheer size is the main reason. Latexian is under 10 MB, while BasicTeX is ~100 MB, and MacTeX is ~2.4 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly prefer TeXMaker to Latexian (have been working with both), but depends on how complicated your document gets. (Texmaker is free; it doesn't have a live preview, but I think it's more flexible as far as compilation goes.) I never had any problems with using LaTeX on a Mac. (You have to install a texmf folder into your library, where you keep the style files if any.)

Answer (score 0):

I use Latexian + MacTex and it works great. I you are just starting out, it's the right combination. Once you get a bit more used to LaTeX, you can try something like Sublime Text + the Latexing plugin. It's more powerful but harder to use.

You can get MacTex here: https://tug.org/mactex/. Just download it and double click on the setup file. Follow the steps and that is it. This is required by Latexing otherwise you can't generate the PDF's

Answer (score 0):

I am new as well. Mactex is the distribution and what I have used to get all the tex stuff.

For an editor I use [Texpad](https://www.texpadapp.com). It is a paid for editor but it si great IMHO, super easy to use, has live preview and a good outline pane. I sure free ones do the same too.

Also think about some sort of versioning system like Github or Subversion. I use Github

Hope it helps